# HTML5 Form Validation With the “pattern”

Tags: regex, html

regex - HTML5 Form Validation:
I’m trying to make a html5 form that contains one input field, and I want it to accept email or phone number (digits) only.
Thanks

Comment: cant you just do `<input type="email" />` ?

Comment: then it will not accept digits

Comment: Oh so basically email or phone number in one input?

Comment: yes, email or phone number in one input

Comment: Try `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*|\d+"`. Note the email regex is taken from [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Basic_validation).

Comment: @MuhammadSeeratAwan post your Markup

Answer (score 1):

This will allow to enter only email address or digits (like phone number) in the input:

```
<input type="text" 
   pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?!([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.))(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\d+" 
>
```

Note that this will not allow to enter country code with a '+' like +1. As only digits are allowed the country code has to be entered like 001, where 00 replace the +.

To allow the '+' replace the last bit of the Regex with:

```
|[+]{0,1}\d+
```